# ShareMediaTask Working in Windows Phone 8.1 device but Not in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am working with a Windows Phone 8 Application.
I wanted to share a partcular image with a specific name.

This is the code snippet I am using.

```
  //Find a Pic that contains the Pic with a particular Name
  var pic = mediaLibrary.SavedPictures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Contains("<name>"));
  ShareMediaTask smt = new ShareMediaTask();
  smt.FilePath = pic.GetPath();
  Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>smt.Show());
```

The strange thing that has come to me is the code is working when I am installing the Application on a Windows Phone 8.1 Device. But When I run it on Windows Phone 8 Device the ShareMediaTask is not Initiating.

I could not figure out whats the problem. I am getting no Exception also when i run in Windows Phone 8 device.

Has any one faced a similar situaton. Am I missing something that is Windows Phone 8 Specific.
Please help me out guys.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the errant behavior? Do you have an app available to receive the data? Does sharing a picture from other apps work?

Comment: On ShareMediaTask.show(); We should be getting a page displaying list of all apps that support image sharing. This screen is not beinbg displayed and I stay in the same screen . Yeah i tested with other apps the sharing of images is working. What do you mean by do you have an app available to receive the data

Answer (score 1):

In `WP8` it's the `CameraCaptureTask` to share a photo which is being selected or captured. So better try inserting the `CameraCaptureTask` in your second line of code rather than `ShareMediaTask`.

[How to use the share media task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207027(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: In the App the user selects the name of the pic that is to be shared. Then again caling CameraCapture Task to selected the pic seems redundant.  Also the strange thing is it is working in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: But your code should work, sorry i couldn't test it here as i'm out. Have a look at this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4aac15/sharing-image-from-windows-phone-8-app/

Comment: I am banging my head from last two days. Its not working on three windows hone 8 devices i have but working on all the windows 8.1 devices. Thanks for you help. Try if you could run it on any WP8 phone